# Remove style on specific tags in Wordpress (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, contains, getelementsbytagname

In Wordpress, `<img>` is inside `<a>` tag like below.

```
<a>link text</a>
<a><img src="#"></a>
```

I added style of dotted border to the bottom of `<a>`, but there's also dotted border under every picture I post.

So I tried to add a function in function.php, in order to remove border of `<a><img src="#"></a>`, but it failed. Please help me with code below.

```
function removeAnchorBorder() {
  var anchorWithPic = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  if (anchorWithPic.contains(img) = true) {
    anchorWithPic.style.border = "none";
}
add_filter("the_content", "removeAnchorBorder");
```

Comment: Why don't you just override it in CSS?

Comment: Maybe it's not clear enough. I had `<a>link</a>` with dotted border-bottom, but there's also border-bottom under the picture, aka  `<a><img></a>` . So I have to remove the border of `<a>` which has `<img>` inside. I cannot set `img {border: none;}` since the border is from `<a>` tag. Is there any way to do with CSS, for this conditional situation?

Comment: Can't you add a specific class on the anchor with the border? And then put the border on that class only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [CSS doesn't have look-ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865298/1225924), you can't override it with plain CSS and must resort to using JavaScript.

This is a very naive approach, with much logic that could be optimized or abstracted to use jQuery if you prefer:

```
var withoutImg = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'),0); 
var withImg = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a img'),0);

withoutImg.forEach(function(node){ 
  node.style.borderStyle = "dotted";
});

withImg.forEach(function(node){ 
  node.parentElement.style.borderStyle = "none";
});
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waRPBo) is a visual example.

Also note that `.forEach()` may not be available in all browsers, and the `Array slice` reference is just a trick to convert the selected NodeList into actual iterable arrays.